# Allowing/Whitelisting Repositories in Binary authorization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am using `alpine docker image` from `https://hub.docker.com` to test `GCP binary authorization` . For this I added the below URLs in the `Images exempt from policy` TAB

```
        docker.io/alpine/*
        hub.docker.com/alpine*
        hub.docker.io/alpine*
```

But the image deployment is still failing with below error

```
 admission webhook "imagepolicywebhook.image-policy.k8s.io" denied the request: Image alpine:3.7 denied by Binary Authorization default admission rule. Denied by always deny admission rule.
```

Following is the `YAML defintion`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: hello-client-allowed
spec:
    # Only run a single pod
  replicas: 1

# Control any pod labeled with app=hello
selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: hello

 # Define pod properties
template:

# Ensure created pods are labeled with app=hello to match the deployment selector
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  # This pod does not require access to the Kubernetes API server, so we prevent
  # even the default token from being mounted
  automountServiceAccountToken: false

  # Pod-level security context to define the default UID and GIDs under which to
  # run all container processes. We use 9999 for all IDs since it is unprivileged
  # and known to be unallocated on the node instances.
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 9999
    runAsGroup: 9999
    fsGroup: 9999

  # Define container properties
  containers:
  - image: alpine:3.7
    name: hello-client-allowed

    # A simple while loop that attempts to access the hello-server service every
    # two seconds.
    command: ["sh", "-c"]
    args: ["while true; do wget -qO- --timeout=2 http://hello-server.default.svc:8080; sleep 2; done"]

    # Container-level security settings
    # Note, containers are unprivileged by default
    securityContext:
      # Prevents the container from writing to its filesystem
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

Comment: your image pattern in alpine*, isn't it? no dockerhub or stuff like that. Can you have a try?

Comment: I think Image pattern must be of the form 'registry/path/to/image'. A trailing '*' is supported as a wildcard.

Comment: Thanks...This is fixed after adding alpine:3.7

Comment: Hi @Zama Ques Can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?